After upgrade to angular 17 bsdatepicker input [readonly property not working
I upgraded my project to angular 17 after that already working bootstrap date picker ready only propert is not working when inspect readonly propery is not showing .but in htm it is set as readonly as true .As part of upgrade I upgraded ngx-bootstrap.Please help me to fix this issue.
Given below is the code in html for input with read only property
 <input type="text" id="date-of-joing" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date Range" bsDaterangepicker
      [readonly]="true" [bsConfig]="{ rangeInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',selectFromOtherMonth: true}"
      [(ngModel)]="dateRangeValue" (ngModelChange)="dateRangeChange($event)" [minDate]="minDate"
      >

In browser this input field is able to edit.

ngx-bootstrap seems not to be compatible with angular 17
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation
